# Перечисление/enum

Tags: java, enum

```
enum MyColors {
    Red,
    Yellow,
    Pink;
}

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyColors color = MyColors.Yellow;

        System.out.println(color.toString());

        switch(color){
        case Pink:
            System.out.println("Выбран розовый");
            break;
        case Red:
            System.out.println("Выбран красый");
            break;
        case Yellow:
            System.out.println("Выбран желтый");
            break;
        }

        int n = color.ordinal();
        System.out.println(n);

    }
}
```

Не могу понять принцип работы перечислений.

1) В начале перечисляются возможные типы цветов: `Red, Yellow, Pink`. 
2) В строке  `MyColors color = MyColors.Yellow;` переменная меняет свой тип с `MyColors` на `Yellow`.
3) `Switch` выбирает `case` `Yellow` т.к. их типы совпадают.
Так ли это?

Comment: Если написать Integer number = 10, Вы же не скажите что number поменял тип с Integer на 10? С перечислениями тоже самое. MyColors тип(класс), а Red, Yellow, Pink - это значения, которые может принимать переменная этого типа. Надо понимать переменной color присвоено значение Yellow

Comment: Мне казалось, что `Red,Yellow, Pink;` - это типы данных, а выходит, что это просто переменные? Зачем тогда нужно перечисление, если я могу проще объявить эти переменные?

Comment: Это не переменные. Это константы типа MyColors. Проще может и сделаете, но enum-ы не зря же имеются во многих языках программирования. Кроме наглядности (видишь имя Yellow, вместо какого-нибудь 12345 и сразу понимаешь что к чему) служат строгим контролем (если положено выбрать между Yelow, Red, Pink, то никаким образом левый 5678 в переменную не запихнёшь в принципе).

Comment: @Kojer Defor  Перечисления позволяют группировать данные и накладывать логическую структуру на них. Например, имя Yellow может присутствовать в различных перечислениях, которые логически означают различные характеристики различных объектов.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> MyColors color = MyColors.Yellow; переменная меняет свой тип с
>   MyColors на Yellow

Тип переменной `color` это `MyColors`, так как эта переменная так и объявлена, как имеющая этот тип.

В объявлении эта переменная инициализируется значением `MyColors.Yellow`, При этом тип переменной не изменился. Просто она стала инициализированной.

В предложении `switch` происходит сравнение значения выражения, заключенного в круглые скобки

```
switch(color){
//....
```

с метками `case`.